# Checking values in chained implementation of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary that uses chaining for values that have the same key which means that `dict[key] = [object1, object2, object3,..., object n]`

I have two objects `year0` and `year1`. I need to find whether or not `year0` and `year1` are within the dictionary at a certain key.

If either `year0` or `year1` are not available then I should move on the the next key. Note: `year0` and `year1` are two different objects.

Unfortunately, I keep getting various errors such as object referenced before assignment or I can't move on to the next key.

Here's my code below for more information:

```
rateLst = []
if year1 > year0: 
    for reg in data.keys():
        slots = data[reg] #slots = [(object[year, index]), object[year, index]
        for value in slots: #value = object[year, index]
            if value.year == year0: 
                index0 = value.index 
            if value.year == year1:
                index1 = value.index
        if index1 is None or index0 is None: #error occurs even if I initialize the values as well it doesn't work
            pass
        else:
            gRate = cagr([index0, index1], year1 - year0)
            rateLst.append((reg, gRate))
return rateLst
```

Thank You <3

Comment: Try initializing index0=None and index1=None after you get the slots. If neither of your conditions value.year==year0 or  value.year == year1 is true then index0 and index1 would be never be created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rateLst = []
if year1 > year0: 
    index0, index1 = None, None
    for reg, slots in data.items():
        #slots = data[reg] #slots = [(object[year, index]), object[year, index]
        for value in slots: #value = object[year, index]
            if value.year == year0: 
                index0 = value.index 
            if value.year == year1:
                index1 = value.index
        if index1 is None or index0 is None: #error occurs even if I initialize the values as well it doesn't work
            pass
        else:
            # You are using OR operator above so there is a chance that index0 or index1 would be None, not sure if this is intended or not
            gRate = cagr([index0, index1], year1 - year0)
            rateLst.append((reg, gRate))
return rateLst
```

Comment: ```rateLst.append((reg, gRate))``` - you don't assign anything to ```reg```.

Comment: @wwii thank, I missed that. Fixed the bug in the code

Comment: Up to the OP, but it seems like ```index0, index1``` would need to be *reset* once both had been found or there will be erroneous entries made in ```rateLst``` while the iteration finishes.

Comment: @wwii true. Infact, the code doesnt even wait for both index1 and index0. I think there are more things that I dont know about so, I just made the suggestion to not get the variable used before assignment error.